# JS Form Validation - Submit Button does nothing

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I'm trying to validate my form, and the first alert works.  But then when the user fills in correct data and clicks submit, the form does not submit anymore.  Any help is appreciated, thanks!

```
<form name="register" action="register.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
```

// form stuff

```
function validateForm() {
if (!checkName() || !checkEmail()) {
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
}

function checkName() {
var name=document.forms["register"]["name"].value;
if (name==null || name=="") {
    alert("Please fill out your name");
    return false;
}
}

function checkEmail() {
var email=document.forms["register"]["email"].value;
var atpos=email.indexOf("@");
var dotpos=email.lastIndexOf(".");
if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=email.length) {
    alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the jQuery validation plugin? It's very widely used and will likely save you a load of pain.

Comment: inline javascript is awful. Please don't do that. You really ought to let javascript handle the whole process using ajax.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments!  I have not tried either of those options, but I thought for my small projects I would not need much.  However, I do think I'll look those both up to try for this project, and to help me in later ones.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need checkEmail and checkName to return true when the email or name is present. What you've got now returns undefined.

[Here is a fiddle showing the solution](http://jsfiddle.net/xnTan/) and here are the two functions rewritten:

```
function checkName() {
    var name = document.forms["register"]["name"].value;
    if (name == null || name == "") {
        alert("Please fill out your name");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function checkEmail() {
    var email = document.forms["register"]["email"].value;
    var atpos = email.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos = email.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (atpos < 1 || dotpos < atpos + 2 || dotpos + 2 >= email.length) {
        alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I do ultimately think you'll be happier if you wind up going to [jQuery Validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/), though.